# MediaStreamSource Raw AAC Frame Size from Mp4 container

Tags: c#, mp4, aac, mediastreamsource

I need to send raw AAC audio frames one at a time to my decoder. I was able to parse the raw AAC bitstream from an MP4 file container, but I'm unable to find any solutions or a way to determine audio frame size.

I have used C# to parse the AAC bistream using the [BMFF library](https://basemedia.codeplex.com/) from Codeplex.

Comment: Which programming language? Have you written any code so far? If so, post it here.

Comment: @GoBusto I have used C# to parse the AAC bistream using Bmff lib from codeplex

Comment: @joshcomley Yes i just had to Parse the Individual samples for MP4 and feed it to the decoder.